# React-Redux: re-rendering a list on add

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I'm adding an invitation component to a list in state, but doing it wrong. I would like, when a successful response comes back from the server, to update the invitations in my state. Right now, that's not happening-it's not even compiling properly.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

My action:

```
export function sendInvitation(props) {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios
            .post(
                `${ROOT_URL}/invitation/invite`,
                {
                    props
                },
                { headers: { authorization: user.token } }
            )
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({ type: INVITATION_SUCCESS, payload: response });
            })
            .catch(response => {
                dispatch(authError(INVITATION_FAILURE, response.response.data.error));
            });
    };
}
```

My reducer:

```
case INVITATION_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, invitations:{...state.invitations, action.payload} };
```

Comment: In state, are `invitations` and array? Or an object?

Comment: @DavinTryon an array of objects. Good call! Now, with this, it works: 

case INVITATION_SUCCESS:
   return { ...state, invitations: [...state.invitations, action.payload] };

Comment: yeah, that looks better.  If was an object, it would have needed a key.

Comment: Want to post an answer and I'll accept?